Blazor interactive server AspNet SignInManager
I know there are already several topics about this but none of them provides a satisfying solution so I want to give it another "year 2024" try.
I have a Blazor Web App using rendermode="InteractiveServer"
Now I want to implement authentication using AspNet Core
In my underlying database there are the corresponding AspNet tables and a corresponding user with the username and password test
My Login Code:
var userName = "test";
var password = "test";

var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
if (user == null)
{
    // User does not exist
}
else
{
    // User exists, so try login
    // THROWS InvalidOperationException
    var signInResult = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, password, false, false);

    if (signInResult.Succeeded)
    {
        // Sign in successful                   
    }
    else
    {
        // Sign in unsuccessful
    }
}

PasswordSignInAsync throws the following error
Error: System.InvalidOperationException: Headers are read-only, response has already started.

What I found out so far is that SignInManager attempts to set an authorization cookie, but since Serverside blazor works over SignalR and no HttpContext is available the error ist thrown.
Is there any clean solution for that?

Are you running that code in a service or in a blazor component/page?

Ive had my own issues trying to work with authentication on blazor server side, due to the lack of HttpContext access. This workaround helped me a lot, but it drops all usages of SignIN and User Managers. I regretably felt the need to do this because all places I found are telling me that thoose things are made to work for webassembly not server side.

The code is in a blazor page

We can create a new blazor web app .net 8 server-side-rendered app, and choosing the authorization type as Individual accounts, so that we will have an application which having your SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync method and working well.

I'm not able to reproduce your issue and I followed the sample created by VS 2022 template and had a login feature test which worked well. Could you pls help check whether you had these services?

builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState(); builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options => {     options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;     options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme; }).AddIdentityCookies(); builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)     .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()     .AddSignInManager()     .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

Adding this to my program.cs still does not fix it. Have you added @rendermode="InteractiveServer" to your App.razor?

Thanks for your reply @CrazyEight, my test is based on the template project and to be honest, it's related to many other components. I can only say it all worked well in my side and I didn't face your exception. Could you pls create a new template project and have a test with it? I think you shall find some useful configurations.

I create a full project on how to reproduce -> https://github.com/Cr4zyEight/BlazorInteractiveServerAspNet
Check the README for Setup instructions as you need a mysql db running

Sorry I don't have an environment to run your complete application. But I still checked your codes, Firstly, I noticed that you are using MudBlazor while I didn't use that, this might cause the difference. Then I noticed that you still have <CascadingAuthenticationState> in Routes.razor, you can  remove it as we already have builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();. The 3rd, you might add @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization in _Imports.razor. I recommend you to create a minimal reproduciable sample for investigation, it will help you narrow down the issue too.
